# Moving from python2 to python3.3 shell_exec output has stopped working

Tags: python-3.x

I have a simple web-based php program developed with my kids to generate lottery numbers.  The php program uses shell_exec to call a python program to work out and print the lottery numbers to the browser.  It worked fine for python2 and now, when running under python3 I just can't seem to get the output back to the browser.  I have changed the python3 program to be a print function.

php program has the following snippet:

```
$c = "python3.3 /Users/Dad/p/sort.py ";
$cmd = $c.$lot;
$oout = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $oout;
```

$lot is a variable from a list box for the type of lottery, e.g. N for National lottery.

From the command line I would invoke - "python3.3 /Users/Dad/p/sort.py N" and I get something like "National Lottery numbers: 5, 6, 11, 27, 28, 49"

Inside the python program, sort.py, the following is used to print the values:

```
        print ("%s: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d" % ( lottery(lot, mainDraw()),
                                                a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5]) )
```

As I wrote above, it works fine printing back to the browser when I change the php program and call sort.py using python2, but I just can't seem to get it to work when I used python3.3!

Any help gratefully received.  I am working on a Mac (Yosemite, 10.10.3) if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you randomize with PHP?

Comment: Try: `$c = "python3.3 /Users/Dad/p/sort.py " . $lot . " 2>&1";`

Comment: Hi dav1d, using the '2>&1' in php it allowed me to see the error that was occurring.  When php was executing it wasn't finding python3.3.  When I qualified the path '/usr/local/bin/python3' then it worked!  Many thanks.  [I now need to update the environment variables so apache can see python3.3 and not python2 as the next step]